# Button in ListView malfunctioning

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

I have a button in each item of a ListView whose background is defined by an XML, one background when enabled and another when disabled. When the ListView loads, it comes out correct. But, for some reason I can't figure out, if I scroll down and then scroll back up, the wrong background shows up.

I'd like to know the solution to this problem, but besides that, in general what I want to accomplish is this:
I have a button in the ListView to take the user to the website for the given item. If there is no website, I want the button to disappear, or be disabled. I seem to have the same problem  with both options.

Thanks in advance for your efforts

Comment: Maybe you are wrong reusing view in `getView()` method? What about some source code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems most likely that the problem lies with your getView() method. Android recycles views to save memory, so, for example, when you scroll down, it calls getView(int, View, ViewGroup) on your adapter where View is the item that just left the top of the screen. If you're not re-populating the item with the new data from the adapter, (ie, just returning convertView) it will put the View that left the top of the screen where the "new" one should be.